# UI Elements showing blue border in Interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Since the latest Xcode updates all the elements of a view appear with a blue border in Interface Builder.
Is there any way to disable this blue border in each view?
When there are many elements in the view this is annoying.

Attached is a sample image

[image: Blue border in each uielement]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go in Menu' Editor->Canvas and make sure the option "Show bounds Rectangles" or "Show Layout Rectangles" is disable.

Comment: sometime simple things can change everything... thank you

Comment: In my case the option wasn't checked, but I still had the blue lines. Cmd+Q then reopening Xcode fixed the issue. Sometimes Xcode just gets in a state.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode:

- > Editor
  >
  > > canvas
  > >
  > > > show Bounds rectangles.

This option show/hide the blue lines.